Driving 6N137 using an open-drain GPIO
Hobbyist here.
I need to fix a bit of a blunder I made.
I created an isolation module for a digital signal using a 6N137 optocoupler; as far as I can tell the module is fine. However, being a fool, I made the input with a push-pull signal in mind (as delineated in the dashed box). My microcontroller uses an open-drain output signal source instead (3V3 but 5V tolerant; Vsig in the schematic) and I suspect changing the firmware into push-pull would be rather ugly a.k.a I prefer to use circuitry here.
This is what I came up with so far to drive the input, mostly using this thread:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I found the SPICE description of the 6N137-LED here:
.MODEL    DEMIT   D
+IS=1.69341E-12 RS=2.5 N=2.4  XTI=4
+EG=1.52436 CJO=1.80001E-11 VJ=0.75 M=0.5 FC=0.5

This is the simulation result on CircuitLab:

I'm a bit concerned about the output voltage taking about 500ns to drop, so I expect my signal output to be distorted. What can I do to alleviate this?
On a breadboard it certainly does something™ of what I want, but I can't really tell if the signal output signal is clean (enough) as my cheap scope maxes out right around this frequency.
So I'm asking for any more blunders I've overlooked and maybe some hints.
EDIT
These are my concrete questions about this circuit:

According to the simulation, the OUT signal (yellow graph) takes about 500 nanoseconds to fall. Why? How can I improve the fall time?
Aforementioned OUT signal approaches about 800mV above GND when off. Why not 0V?


How much current can the MCU pin sink, at what voltage? Do you care if the output is inverted?

@TimWilliams, it's a STM32F103, so the pin can sink 20mA max, 8mA recommended, and it's 5V tolerant. Also, I don't care if output is inverted.

You might be looking at a routine delay in the optocoupler, at 500ns.  I'm assuming you're looking at the opto output, not shown in your schematic.  If so, you could try giving that pullup (on the opto output) a higher value and see if it affects it.  I wouldn't blame your scope, since the other edges (including the yellow rising) are nice and squared up.

@Justme There's a wired-logic situation at play as well, so the input is actually multiple open-drain-pins wired together. Changing the code in that situation is not simply the pin mode reg ;)

Why can't you simply change the pin to push-pull? The change is literally one or two bits in the pin mode register. Also the opto input can be driven with open drain output if you wire it so. Also the part about having multiple output wired together should be added to the question as it affects the answers.

@Justme I'm aware that I can change the wiring, but I've already got that part of the circuit manufactured and on hand; I want to know what's viable without the need to manually modify a PCB.

@CristobolPolychronopolis I'm not really concerned about the rising edge, but the falling edge taking almost 1/4 of the off-time in the simulation

The basic problem is getting Q2 to shut off -- there's a lot of charge stored in its base, and R2 is the only place for it to go. Reducing R2 to 1000 ohms helps tremendously. And Spehro's idea of using a Schottky diode to keep Q2 from saturating in the first place works even better.

@DaveTweed "R2 is the only place for it to go" ~ why can't I grasp this? While SIG is low, Q1 should pull Q2's base low; Q2 will be on. Doesn't that mean Q2's base is discharged, or are we talking about electron direction instead of conventional current direction?

No, when Q2 is on, there is significant current through its base (about 3 mA) and significant voltage between its emitter and base (about 0.7 V) -- it is certainly not "discharged". When Q1 cuts off, R2 is the only remaining path for this current, which is driven by the charge stored in Q2's base region relative to its emitter.

The first thing I did with your simulation was to add a voltage probe at the base of Q2. This immediately made the issue clear to me. I'll never understand why people run simulations and then ignore 90% of the information that they can provide.

@DaveTweed it's because the exact locations to find "relevant" or "interesting" information are not obvious to my learner's eyes, but I'm grateful for anyone willing to help!

Not really an excuse -- after all, your circuit has only 3 nodes that are not connected directly to voltage sources. You're already probing one of them; adding the other two is hardly an onerous task, and you'd gain a lot of insight.

Anyway, to answer your second question, the LED voltage doesn't drop below 800 mV because that's the point at which the LED current drops to a trivial level. If you really care about that, add a pull-down resistor in parallel with the LED.

The reason for the delay is an inherent problem with bipolar devices (including BJTs, IGBTs, PN diodes, thyristors, and more esoteric devices): They all take some time to turn off, relating to the time it takes for free carriers to recombine in and near the junction. You can avoid the issue by using unipolar devices like MOSFETs, JFETs, or Schottky diodes, but of course these have their own idiosyncrasies. You can also add components to prevent the bipolar device from turning that far on (cf. "Baker clamp"), or use gold- or platinum-doped devices with shorter carrier lifetime (cf. "FRED").

Sure, that works.  Since the pin(s) is 5V tolerant, you can even do away with the cascode:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Actually we can even do it if it's not 5V-tolerant: R5 is optional, pulling it down mildly in the off-state.  I would recommend values R2 = 4.7k, R1 = 10k, R5 = ∞ for 5V-tolerant operation, or as shown for 3.3V-only operation.
You may find R4 useful: it discharges Q1 and D1's capacitance and stored charge, whereas letting the LED self-discharge gives a cascaded-exponential curve with a very long tail.  The current drops quickly below threshold, but a sharper cutoff helps just that little bit.
R4 can also be avoided by using a non-inverting drive scheme, like Michal Podmanický's answer shows.
Q1's stored charge is the majority of turn-off time in your proposed solution; the problem is the ratio of R1 to R2.  Driving the base on much harder than needed, stores excess charge, which needs to be discharged (by R2, and recombination current).  Figure hFE(sat) around 20-30 (for a typical hFE = 200 part) to get a good compromise between VCE(sat), turn-on/off time, and reliability vs. temperature and manufacture (VBE(on) variation).
Other solutions are possible, but require things you may not have, or are simpler in one respect but more complicated in another.
For example, you could drive the LED directly:

simulate this circuit
but you'll have to change one (1) component on the already-made board (short out the resistor / replace with 0-ohm jumper).  Or keep the resistor,

simulate this circuit
but need a higher voltage supply, or a CCS instead of the pull-up resistor.  (And if you were doing a CCS, you might as well switch it instead.)  Both alternatives also draw continuous supply current, which may or may not be a concern.
There is one advantage to the shunting architecture: the LED's stored charge is removed immediately.  This may be helpful in high-bandwidth applications.

I really appreciate the simplicity of your answers! bridging/shorting the on-board resistor is easy, and I've noticed it even works with a pull-up of 1K against 3V3 i.e. 1.9mA LED current or 3.3mA through GPIO drain. Thank you so much!

Here is an improved circuit:

M1 is used instead of a BJT and Schottky diode D1 prevents Q1 from saturating.
Simulating what you have I get a pretty nasty waveform of LED current:

I've plotted voltage input (driven from a stiff voltage source) vs. LED current, which is what produces the light. We don't really care about LED voltage.
But I think you'd be better off changing the pin(s) to push-pull, even if you have to add a logic gate or whatever.
Or just drive the LED directly with the output since it's 5V-tolerant. Just a resistor to +5 and the optocoupler LED, assuming the output can handle the current.

Replacing the BAT54 with a BAS70 as per Tim Williams' suggestion we get a further improvement


BAT54 is rather large for baker clamping -- it only makes things worse; give BAS70 a try, though.

@TimWilliams Even a 1N5819 helps in this case, but the BAS70 is an excellent improvement. See above edit.

Your circuit doesn’t have Led discharging path, that’s why it has slow turn off. (A Led has some capacity).
Make a push-pull from open drain with transistor:

Using fast schottky instead 1n4148 can help since it pulls the Led closer to Gnd during output Low.
This should also provide fast turning off:


The capacitance of the LED isn't the problem -- it's the charge storage in the base of OP's Q2 that's the problem.
